# django annotate - conditional count

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter, django-annotate

I have a model called 'StoreItem' and a model named 'QuoteItem'. A QuoteItem points on a StoreItem.

I'm trying to annotate a counter of how many quote items point on store items, but with conditions to apply on the quote items.

I tried something like this:

```
items = items.annotate(
            quote_count=Count(
                Case(
                    When(quoteitem__lookup_date__in=this_week, then=1), 
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )
        )
```

'items' are a queryset of StoreItems. 'this_week' is a list of dates representing this week (that's the filter I try to apply). After I make the dates thing work I want to add more filters to this conditional count but lets start with that.

Anyway what I'm getting is more like a boolean - if Quote Items that match the condition exists, no matter how many I have, the counter will be 1. else, will be 0.

It looks like the `Count(Case())` only check if any item exist and if so return 1, while I want it to iterate over all quote items that point on the store item and count them, if they match the condition (individually).

How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to wrap everything in a `Sum` statement instead of `Count` (I find it a bit odd that `Count` works at all):

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Sum, When

items = items.annotate(
        quote_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(quoteitem__lookup_date__in=this_week, then=1), 
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )
```

This basically adds up all the `0`s and `1`s for the inner `Case` statement, resulting in a count of the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a similar task. For me, `Sum` over the `Case/When` was not working due to how many tables I was joining (it was way over counting). Ended up like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Count, When, F

items = items.annotate(
        quote_count=Count(
            Case(
                When(quoteitem__lookup_date__in=this_week, then=F('quoteitem__id'), 
            ),
            distinct=True,
        )
    )
```

In my case I actually had to add two `Count`s together like:

```
items = items.annotate(
        quote_count=Count(
            Case(
                When(quoteitem__lookup_date__in=this_week, then=F('quoteitem__id'), 
            ),
            distinct=True,
        )
    ) + Count (
            Case(
                When(itemgroup__lookup_date__in=this_week, then=F('itemgroup__quoteitem__id'), 
            ),
            distinct=True,
        )
```

Assuming that `items` can be related to `quoteitems` either through an `itemgroup` or directly.